# Open nav-tab-content then scroll down in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Hello I have two functions which are working. I understand a little about how programming works but I dont have background in javascript or jquery (idk).

This function opens a nav tab-content:

```
<script> function homeTab() {
    $('[href="#nav-home"]').tab('show');
     } 
</script>
```

This function auto scrolls to the shopping div at the bottom:

```
<script>
    $('#nav-shop-tab').click(function () {
         var sectionTo = $(this).attr('href');
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $(sectionTo).offset().top
          }, 1500);
       });
</script>
```

*Functions above are all working*

Home and Shop are in the same page. Shop is in bottom
[image]

This is the about tab

[image: About tab]

What I want is how can I merge these two functions? so that when I click a button(SHOP at GCO) it will first open the "home" tab then scroll down to the shopping div?

Is it possible? I'm open to other solutions as well so that I can learn more. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i made some fix, try changing the function when you click the shop tab to this

```
  $('#nav-shop-tab').click(function () {
            $("#nav-home-tab").click();
            setTimeout(() => {
                var sectionTo = $(this).attr('href');
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(sectionTo).offset().top
            }, 1500);
            }, 200);
           
        });
```

Comment: Hello thank you for the response but sadly it doesnt work. All of the contents above are in a single html file

Comment: please share the code and i will see, it has to work

Comment: Here. https://jsfiddle.net/romexblue/zt7bjpr2/6/    I dont know how to refer to filename in jsfiddle but yeah I tried to write MidTerm.html#shopping in the href it does not work for me

Comment: i edited my answer, check if its good now